# Change the file name of VMWare-related project files

Tags: vmware-workstation

How to change the VMWare-related project file names to something else?

In the below example, I want to change from `Windows XP Professional.*` to `Clean Stat.*` . Any idea how to do this?

[http://lh3.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SggTlK7O9EI/AAAAAAAAEv0/of-dIz6U110/s400/vmwarechangename.jpg](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/I7KuXNObXdPijpgnbwdC8w?feat=embedwebsite)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to mannualy change the name. There is not a method within VMware that will change the files names.

If I recall the file names are also stored within the .vmx file. This is just a plain text file you can edit in Notepad.

After changing the file name references there you should be able to rename the files and the system should run under the new name.

Please make a backup of the .vmx file first :-)

Answer (score 0):

As [Richard writes in his answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/6970/change-the-file-name-of-vmware-related-project-files/6978#6978) you can rename files "manually." If you make a mistake though, you could lose your file.

A simple trick is, to shut down the and migrate the VM to a different datastore. All relevant files will be renamed.